# Central Administration access denied on single box

Tags: central-administration

In our farm, we have deployed Central Administration to multiple servers and we're using a load balancer to redirect requests to one of those servers.

Now for some reason, one of the servers sometimes denies us access to CA. It's the same server every time. Restarting the application pool solves the problem, but after some time (different every time), the problem pops up again.

Although it's not really impacting operations and is easily resolvable, I'd still like to find out why this happens and how we can avoid this. So I was wondering if anyone has ever encountered this behavior? Perhaps not on CA but on a normal site?

Update on setup:

- Central Admin service is running on 2 application servers and one front-end.
- The URL is loadbalanced between the 2 application servers.
- AAM has the SPCA URL configured as default, the three servernames are added as internal URLs for the default zone.
- Unicast / multicast: no idea to be honest

Comment: Can you share your farm topology and load balancing details like hardware/software , unicast or multicast and failover details. Additionally, please share your alternate accessing mappings for the central admin site.

Comment: Ok, added some detail (see above)